# PHP MySQL Query on some letters only and then return shortest string?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have for example, the following data in my database table...

```
A Bridge Too Far
A Bridge Too Far trilogy
A bridge Too Far the sequel
Goodfellas the return of Pesci
Goodfellas
Goodfellas 2
Goodfellas 3
```

etc. etc. there will also be some unique entries as well as more like the above

What I want to display is only:

```
A Bridge Too Far
Goodfellas
```

Essentially get rid of extra info around the original title which is not needed.

I'm thinking I need to maybe do a check on a number of letters in first word before a space then if that's over say 5 letters match with the next rows, if it does then keep adding the rows to a list somehow then when it stops matching spit out the shortest one? If the first word is less than 5 letters then move onto second word (just trying to avoid, the :: them :: this :: their etc etc)

I have tried to think logically about this from an SQL/PHP point of view but am struggling, is it even possible?

All help appreciated.

Darren

Phil :: Thanks - your version works on sqlize but mine does not!

Here's the actual code I'm using:

```
$sql = mysql_query("create temporary table movies (name VARCHAR(255))",$db);        

$sql2 = mysql_query("create temporary table movies2 (name VARCHAR(255))",$db);

$sql3 = mysql_query("insert into movies(name) select title from PRprod_FILMS where genre = 'Action  Adventure'",$db);

$sql4 = mysql_query("insert into movies2(name) select name from movies",$db);

// both tables movies and movies2 identical now

$sql5 = mysql_query("
  SELECT * FROM movies m 
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM movies2 m2
        WHERE m.name LIKE CONCAT(m2.name, '%')
        AND LENGTH(m2.name) < LENGTH(m.name)) order by name
        ",$db);

while ($sql55 = mysql_fetch_array($sql5)){ // aa

echo $sql55[name]."<br />";

    } // close aa

mysql_close();
```

I still get things like below:

```
2 Fast 2 Furious
2 Fast 2 Furious Bluray 2003
2 Fast 2 Furious Box Set DVD
2 Fast 2 Furious DVD
2 Fast 2 Furious HD DVD 2003 US Import

Bad Boys Collectors Edition DVD Wide Screen
Bad Boys DVD
Bad Boys DVD 1983
Bad Boys DVD 1995
Bad Boys DVD Superbit Wide Screen
```

Where I simply want: 2 Fast 2 Furious && Bad Boys DVD

Any ideas?

Darren

Thanks again Phil but I'm still getting:

```
310 To Yuma BluRay
310 To Yuma DVD 2007
310 To Yuma DVD Wide Screen
```

I guess another way of saying what I want is:

If the first 5 characters (obv. to include spaces) match, once they stop matching get rid of what's left and print the result. Now, i also have to be careful once again with this as "The Hangover" && "The Hangover 2" are refectly plausible!

Possible?

Darren

Also, I just had a look at some samples to see if I can work out how to progress and noticed...

A sample of the original list if I simply print titles shows:

```
0091 Vol3 DVD
02 in H20 A SelfHelp Course on Breathing in Swimmi... // missing
0430 DVD // missing
1 2 3 4 5 DVD // missing
1 Night In Paris DVD // missing
10 Best Fitness DVD // missing
10 Best Fitness Five Discs DVD // missing
10 DVD 1979 // missing
10 Hollywood Leading Men DVD
```

and after the query:

```
0091 Vol3 DVD
10 Hollywood Leading Men DVD
```

notice 7 lines are missing between "0091 Vol3 DVD" && "10 Hollywood Leading Men DVD"

Comment: what do you mean, please elaborate.

Comment: What are the requirements for the selection?  Why don't you want to select the other ones?  Will `WHERE name='A Bridge Too Far'` OR `WHERE name = 'Goodfellas'` not do?

Comment: @Darren I think you missed the point of my example. You shouldn't be creating temp tables

Comment: Why allow The Hangover sequel but not those for Goodfellas?

Comment: OK, bad example on my part, agreed. The "2 fast 2 furious" and "bad boys" examples above are better - basically, I'm trying to strip crap from around movie names but only have one of each left

Answer (score 3):

Try this...

```
SELECT `title` FROM `PRprod_FILMS` m
WHERE `genre` = 'Action  Adventure'
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM `PRprod_FILMS` m2
    WHERE m.`title` LIKE CONCAT(m2.`title`, '%')
    AND LENGTH(m2.`title`) < LENGTH(m.`title`)
    AND m2.`genre` = m.`genre`
)
ORDER BY `title`;
```

Here's an example - http://www.sqlize.com/HIaf4zr69L (uses two identical temp tables as you can't reference the same temp table more than once in MySQL)

### Update

Using your sample set, I get

```
A Bridge Too Far
Goodfellas
2 Fast 2 Furious
Bad Boys Collectors Edition DVD Wide Screen
Bad Boys DVD
310 To Yuma BluRay
310 To Yuma DVD 2007
310 To Yuma DVD Wide Screen
```

The reason for the apparent duplicates is because it is only eliminating extensions of shorter strings. To explain...

You eliminate "Bad Boys DVD 1983" and "Bad Boys DVD 1995" because they are extensions of "Bad Boys DVD". "Bad Boys Collectors Edition DVD Wide Screen" remains in the result set because it is not an extension of any other pattern. If you added "Bad Boys", you would eliminate all except for that.

Comment: +1 Note that you can easily copy tables with `create temporary table movies2 select * from movies;` in your code sample.

Comment: Thanks @mellamokb - was using that anyway, answer appreciated though

Comment: @DarrenSweeney They were referring to my SQLize example only. Using real tables, you need only one. I've updated my answer to match your setup

Comment: @DarrenSweeney I've added some more information. Your best bet it to make sure the shortest version of a title exists without any embellishments

Comment: Thanks Phil, but that still doesn't help 100% as the query is stripping a lot of legitimite entries from the list which have no duplicates as shown in my last question edit. Going to repost the question and hopefully make a little clearer. Your help is appreciated.